# Terraform provisioner error for multiple instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When running the below file with Terraform I get the following error:

> Resource 'aws_instance.nodes-opt-us-k8s' not found for variable
>   'aws_instance.nodes-opt.us1-k8s.id'.

Do I need to include the provisioner twice because my 'count' variable is creating two? When I just include one for 'count' variable I get the error my Ansible playbook needs to run playbook files, which makes since because it is empty until I figure this error out.

I am in the early stages with Terraform and Linux so pardon my ignorance

```
#-----------------------------Kubernetes Master & Worker Node Server Creations----------------------------

#-----key pair for Workernodes-----

resource "aws_key_pair" "k8s-node_auth" {
  key_name   = "${var.key_name2}"
  public_key = "${file(var.public_key_path2)}"
}

#-----Workernodes-----

resource "aws_instance" "nodes-opt-us1-k8s" {
  instance_type = "${var.k8s-node_instance_type}"
  ami           = "${var.k8s-node_ami}"
  count         = "${var.NodeCount}"

  tags {
    Name = "nodes-opt-us1-k8s"
  }

  key_name               = "${aws_key_pair.k8s-node_auth.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.opt-us1-k8s_sg.id}"]
  subnet_id              = "${aws_subnet.opt-us1-k8s.id}"

  #-----Link Terraform worker nodes to Ansible playbooks-----

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOD
cat <<EOF >> workers
[workers]
${self.public_ip}
EOF
EOD
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok --instance-ids ${aws_instance.nodes-opt-us1-k8s.id} --profile Terraform && ansible-playbook -i workers Kubernetes-Nodes.yml"
  }
}
```

Comment: You just want `self.id` here

Comment: Thanks...that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform 0.12.26 resolved similar issue for me (when using multiple file provisioners when deploying multiple VMs to Azure)

Hope this helps you: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22006

Answer (score 0):

When using a provisioner and referring to the resource the provisioner is attached to you need to use the [`self` keyword](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#attributes-of-your-own-resource) as you've already spotted with what you are writing to the file.

So in your case you want to use the following provisioner block:

```
...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOD
cat <<EOF >> workers
[workers]
${self.public_ip}
EOF
EOD
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok --instance-ids ${self.id} --profile Terraform && ansible-playbook -i workers Kubernetes-Nodes.yml"
  }
```